# MSO post listing bug?

Tags: support, migration, specific-question, question-lists

I'm seeing the same post twice (with different vote counts, and one marked as migrated) yet when I click on them, they lead to exactly the same question, showing the same vote counts.  What's up???  Popular question?  Alien invasion taking over the satellites? :)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question was migrated to Server Fault's meta, which migrated it back to Meta Stack Overflow, resulting in two copies of the question.

If you click on the original copy (the one with the `[migrated]` in the title), you get thrown into a redirect chain that lands you on the new copy:

[image: redirect chain for question]

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that could happen... I guess I haven't come across too many migrated questions.  Out of curiosity, which is the one with the migrated tag... the original or the received migration?

Comment: Usually questions don't get tossed back and forth like this, so it's not something you'd see happen too often. The original has the migrated tag, to indicate that it was "migrated away" to Server Fault's meta.